# Database Design - how to store quantities that are measured in different ways

Tags: database, database-design

I would like to know if the database design i have in mind for an online food store is good according to the usually followed standards and conventions.

Basically the confusion i have is how to store items whose quantity is measured in different ways.

For example, there are items that are measured in terms of kilograms and then there are items measured in terms of number of packets.

For example rice is measured in kilograms and something like say, Noodles would be measured in terms of number of packets.

so the tables are planned to have below fields:

Items table with the fields: category,name,company,variant and a boolean variable named measured_in_packets?..

for items where measured_in_packets is set to true, an entry in another table will hold the available packet sizes:

packet_sizes table with item_id and packet_size..

so if one product is available in multiple packet sizes (250 gm, 500 gm etc), a row would be made for each available size against the item id...

does this sound like a good database design?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: I believe this is a legitimate question. The OP has properly described what they do and don't understand, where they're stuck, what they're current design looks like, etc. The formatting may not be great, but that can easily be improved.

Comment: I also updated the title to make it more closely reflect the actual question. Feel free to roll it back if it doesn't accurately reflect what you were originally intending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell, you have items which have a quantity value, but that quantity value can be measured in different kinds of measurement types. You gave examples such as kilograms, packages, and we can perhaps add others such as litres for liquids, etc.

One of the problems with the current solution is that is doesn't allow for any easy alteration or expansion. It also relies on the checking of a boolean field in order to make decisions (such as which table to join I believe, based on your description).

Instead, a better approach would be to create a table containing the possible measurement types, such as kilograms or packets. Your `items` then simply have a foreign key to this table, and that tells you how the item is measured. This allows you to expand the types in the future, and no need to maintain a boolean flag, or do any other manual work.

This diagram illustrates what I'm referring to:

[image]

So if the data in these tables looked like this:

**items**

```
+----+---------+----------+----------------------+
| id | name    | quantity | measurement_types_id |
+----+---------+----------+----------------------+
|  1 | Rice    |       50 |                    1 |
|  2 | Noodles |       75 |                    2 |
+----+---------+----------+----------------------+
```

**measurement_types**

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+
| id | name      | measurement_symbol |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1 | Kilograms | kg                 |
|  2 | Packets   | packets            |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
```

A practical example of this data using the following query:

```
SELECT items.name, items.quantity, measurement_types.measurement_symbol 
FROM items 
INNER JOIN measurement_types 
    ON measurement_types.id = items.measurement_types_id;
```

would yield this result:

```
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| name    | quantity | measurement_symbol |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
| Rice    |       50 | kg                 |
| Noodles |       75 | packets            |
+---------+----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. However I would not be adding a quantity field in the Items table. For items where the measurement is done in Kgs or Litres, users would be presented with the option of entering in the number of Kg's or Litres of the item.

Comment: @user3311539 Where would you be putting the quantity then? Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but regardless of what type of measurement value they're entering (be it kilograms or litres), its still a numeric value, so would you not simply have them enter the quantity, and then set the proper measurement type foreign key when the record is created / updated?

Comment: And for items where packets are the measurement unit, how about a separate table (named packet_sizes) which stores the item id and the available sizes. For example for Noodles, if the item id is 4, in the table packet_sizes there would be separate rows for each available packet size. Users would be presented the option to select the number of packets and size of each packet. what is the opinion on this?

Comment: the Items table is a master table where the details of all the items will be stored. The quantity would be stored in a seperate table Orders, which contains the user_id and the item name

Comment: @user3311539 Ahh ha, ok, so I think we've had a bit of a miscommunication. So what your original question was talking about is how, and in how many ways, the individual item is measured (**not** an inventory of how many you have on hand as I originally thought); So a Rice item can come in packages of 100 kg, 200 kg, etc, and noodles can come in packets of 4, 8, and 12, for example. The user can then "order", for example, the 2 noodles of the 4-pack variety (which is a separate table on its own). Is this more correct?

Comment: how **many** you have on hand = how **much** you have on hand, to be clear

Comment: Actually in our country, there are few things which are not available in packets at all (non-branded items) such as rice, grains etc. These items are packed and given to customers based on their requirement in whatever quantity they want.. for these items users would be given two adjacent text boxes one to enter the Kilos and one to enter the grams eg. 2Kg 300 gm...

Comment: then there are items available only in packets(branded items) which can be given to customers only in the quantity made available by the manufacturer. for eg noodles are available in packets alone of standard sizes eg. 250 gms, 500 gms etc. for such items the customers are presented two text boxes ..one to fill in number of packets and one to fill in weight. eg. 2 packets of 500 gms. For these packet items, a separate table packet_sizes will record the item_id and the quantity..hope its clear now

Comment: @user3311539 Ok, I think I understand better now, let me try again: In short, we have a concept of packet, and non-packet items. Packet items come in pre-defined sizes such as 500g, 750g, 1000g, etc for example. Non-packet items have an unconstrained quantity, and can come in whatever quantity they want (I could order 100 grams of rice, or 829 grams of rice). Is that more correct?

Comment: @user3311539 Also, one bit of confusion: You said *for [non-packet items] users would be given two adjacent text boxes one to enter the Kilos and one to enter the grams*; first, by "kilos" I want to make sure you mean "kilograms", and if that is the case, I'm confused why you would need to two text boxes to enter kilograms and grams? If I wanted to order 5 kilograms and 142 grams, could I not simply write it in the kilogram box as "5.142"?

Comment: yup you have understood the concept of Non-paclet items and Packet items correctly.By Kilos, i meant Kilograms. The reason why two test boxes are provided is to match the genearl way in which non-packeted items would be measured. i.e in general people say they want 1 kg 200 gm of rice rather that say 1.2 kg of rice..

Comment: @user3311539 Oh ok, I see. Alright, I will reconsider my answer and post an update as soon as I can.